# How to Setup IIS 7.5 Website Physical Path to a Network Share?

Tags: networking, iis-7, iis-7.5

How to Setup IIS 7.5 Website Physical Path to a Network Share?

When I point the physical path to a network share and try to access the page, I get the following error:

[Error IIS 7.5 http://grab.by/3hho](http://grab.by/3hho)

Answer (score 2):

The account which IIS is running under needs to have the appropriate permissions to access the file share on \192.168.0.250. If you are part of a domain you need to have a domain account to use as the service account so that IIS has permission to access the share.

This has been [discussed on the IIS.net](http://forums.iis.net/t/1110715.aspx) forums.